# How to install PHP `mbstring` extension in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, php, extension

What is the  PHP `mbstring` extension, and what is the best way to install it on Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 244, accepted):

**EDIT:** [Dylan Pierce](https://askubuntu.com/users/382863/dylan-pierce) has confirmed that you can already install some PHP 7.2 extensions in the same way you would for PHP 5. For `mbstring` in particular, you can execute:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

To complement [sparkmood](https://askubuntu.com/users/40751/sparkmood)'s answer, this now works for PHP 7.2 if you already imported ondrej's PPA for it.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.2
```

Don't forget, either PHP 7 is available through ubuntu's official repositories or you will need an external PPA.

Comment: After installing this package, where is the mbstring extension? I can't find it in `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available` like the others. I've tried uncommenting the extension in `php.ini` but it doesn't know the the path to the extension.

Comment: I can't find it as well. I needed it to install software that performed a check on PHP extensions and `mbstring` was one of the required ones. It recognised it as installed, so even though I'm not sure where it is, I guess it's in there, somewhere! Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: I've figured it out:

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring`

Also works for other php extensions you might need like:
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-dom`

I really like how brainless it is to install/activate these modules. I just wish I didn't have to go on an internet wide goose chase for them.

Comment: I initially tried to install it like you did but some of the extensions where not available, and I tried not too long ago. This is cool though, because it seems more and more work is being done in the PHP 7.0 versions!

Comment: Why is nobody fighting this version-in-name stuff? -_-

Comment: I believe that as soon as version 7 covers all of the old 5 libraries, you won't have to write 7 to get the latest and greatest. Not doing so would probably break build scripts or cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: After installed in Ubuntu 16.04 with LAMP is needed to restart Apache2 service `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: You can just use package `php-mbstring` without the version number

Comment: Do you need to enable the extension in the php.ini file? Some tutorial I was following wants me to do that in the /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini file, but two other tutorials don't mention doing this.

Answer (score 50):

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

I have installed mbstring in php7.0-fpm (7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4)

Comment: This is correct for Debian Stretch. No need to add the version number. 
Internally a sub-package with version number is loaded.

Comment: I have added version because i have tested on above version. thanks for you comment

Comment: This is vastly superior to specifying the version on the cli as it seems to adapt to the installed version.

Comment: My experience using the sury package repo on debian 9 (stretch), I had to specify the 7.2 version, because php-mbstring is only supported until php 7.2. By not using the php prefix version, it kept saying it doesn't exist since by php7.4 (the latest release of php as of today). Make sure to install only php7.2 and not above or it might not work as expected.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php-mbstring (on buster)

Comment: @geoidesic First update sudo apt-get update and then try

Answer (score 27):

mbstring is built in libapache2-mod-php5 package, so you can use this command for installing :

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

As described in package [details](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/httpd/libapache2-mod-php5) :

```
 dba dom ereg exif fileinfo filter ftp gettext hash iconv json libxml
 mbstring mhash openssl pcre Phar posix Reflection session shmop SimpleXML
 soap sockets SPL standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tokenizer wddx xml
 xmlreader xmlwriter zip zlib.
```

Comment: I have already installed apache2 on my server now if I install "libapache2-mod-php5" on my server will it any problem.

Comment: When I run your line, it break my LAMP - l have to re-install :(

Comment: This is poor advice. While some systems have Apache2 installed, many others may not. Executing this command risks breaking otherwise working systems. (Yes, I know I'm years late, but maybe it'll help someone not try this fix.)

Answer (score 9):

**If you're using php 5.6**

Install php 5.6 mbstring package:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mbstring
```

Then add the following line to the bottom of your php.ini file:

```
extension=php5.6-mbstring.so
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

To find your php.ini file, create a file and insert the following line:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then open with a browser to see where your php.ini file is located.

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was already installed, but I just needed to do `phpenmod mbstring`, followed by `apachectl graceful`.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 14.04 extension *mbstring* should be built in.

For Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

See also [Introduction to Multibyte String](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php)

Answer (score 1):

It requires adding another source for apt for install in 18.04..

Download Page for php7.2-mbstring_7.2.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb on AMD64 machines

If you are running Ubuntu, it is strongly suggested to use a package manager like aptitude or synaptic to download and install packages, instead of doing so manually via this website.

You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line to your /etc/apt/sources.list like this:

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe

Comment: +1 I had to use this solution as well for my Google Cloud Ubuntu 18.04 LTS install before I could use apt-get for the 7.2 mbstring extension, then I was able to use the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the mcrypt itself (the package that php-mcrypt uses to do its crypt stuff) is no longer supported after PHP7.2, As of today, to install it specifically for php7.2, you'll need to make sure when installing to prefix all php7.2 extensions with `php7.2-`.

While initially the commands suggested by others to just install it work, when using it with an  framework version that requires mcrypt (such as Laravel4.2), it will require you to install mcrypt using pecl. Follow the [fix here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54230152/1345527)