# How to fix php7.0-mbstring for PHP 7.0.12?

Tags: php

When I try to install `php7.0-mbstring` I get the following error :

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-mbstring : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) but 7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

PS: `php -v` gives the following output :

```
PHP 7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.12-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: See the first answer relating to Ondrej PPA... http://askubuntu.com/questions/491629/how-to-install-php-mbstring-extension-in-ubuntu

Comment: The only solution I found is to rollback PHP to 7.0.8.